# Tabela de contingência em R

Tags: r, reshape

Eu tenho uma tabela que se resume no seguinte:

```
Destino; Proposito; Custo;<br/>
Chicago; Negocios; 35;<br/>
Nova York; Negocios; 30;<br/>
Miami; Turismo; 25;<br/>
Chicago; Estudo; 50;<br/>
Nova York; Turismo; 40;<br/>
Miami; Estudo; 90;<br/>
Miami; Estudo; 110;<br/>
Chicago; Turismo; 30;<br/>
Miami; Negocios; 20;<br/>
Chicago; Turismo; 35;<br/>
Nova York; Negocios; 40;<br/>
Chicago; Estudo; 150;<br/>
Nova York; Turismo; 40;<br/>
Miami; Negocios; 30;<br/>
Nova York; Estudo; 140;<br/>
Chicago; Turismo; 35;<br/>
Nova York; Turismo; 40;<br/>
```

Eu estou tentando escrever um script em R que transforme esses dados numa tabela de contigência com a seguinte configuração:

```
Destino; Negocios; Turismo; Estudo; Total;<br/>
Miami; 50; 25; 200; 275;<br/>
Chicago; 35; 100; 150; 285;<br/>
Nova York; 70; 120; 140;<br/>
Total; 155; 130; 545;<br/>
```

A ideia é ter uma matriz com a somatória de custos por "Destino" e por "Proposito" simultaneamente.

O máximo que consegui, depois de muita ajuda de meus colegas com experiência em SQL, foi:

```
require(sqldf)
%>% df
select Detino,
       sum(case when carater = 'Estudo'   then Custo else 0 end) as P_Estudo,
       sum(case when carater = 'Turismo'  then Custo else 0 end) as P_Turismo,
       sum(case when carater = 'Negocios' then Custo else 0 end) as P_Negocios,
       sum(Custo) as Total
from df
group by Destino
```

A tarefa seria mais fácil se o objetivo fosse obter os custos totais por "Destino" ou por "Proposito". Há varias formas de faze-lo empregrando as funções `group_by` do pacote `dplyr`, ou `aggregate` ou `xtabs`.

Agradeço qualquer sugestão que possa me ajudar a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Tente rodar os comando com `>` na frente, assumindo que seus dados estão dentro de um data frame chamado `df`:

```
> library(reshape2)
> acast(df, Destino ~ Proposito, fun.aggregate=sum)

Using Custo as value column: use value.var to override.
           Estudo  Negocios  Turismo
Chicago       200        35      100
Miami         200        50       25
Nova York     140        70      120
```

Agora basta adicionar as margens com os totais:

```
> addmargins(acast(df, Destino ~ Proposito, fun.aggregate=sum))

Using Custo as value column: use value.var to override.
           Estudo  Negocios  Turismo
Chicago       200        35      100
Miami         200        50       25
Nova York     140        70      120
```

Percebe que no segundo bloco de comandos eu repeti o comando `acast`. Na verdade, não é necessário separar isto em duas etapas. Fiz assim para ser um passo a passo, para melhorar a compreensão.